# How to get only past 2 days events using getPastEvents everytime?

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps, events, react

How can the following query be modified to only fetch the past two days worth of events:

```
const events= await MyContract.getPastEvents("eventName", {
  fromBlock: 0,
  toBlock: "latest"
});
```

Comment: My guess is that you have to check when blocks where mined and decide which one to pass as `fromBlock`.

Comment: const events= await MyContract.getPastEvents("EventName", {
        fromBlock: (await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()) - 12343, // apprx 12343 blocks every 2 days
        toBlock: "latest"
      });

Answer (score 1):

There's approximately 12,343 blocks every two days, so finding the current block number and subtracting that amount would give the block number to target. Pass that in as the `fromBlock` parameter to the `getPastEvents` function to limit to that range:

```
const events= await MyContract.getPastEvents("EventName", {
  fromBlock: (await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()) - 12343,
  toBlock: "latest"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getBlock = async () => {
    const result = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
    return web3.utils.hexToNumberString(result)
    
}

const calculated = getBlock().then((res) => { const calculated = Number(res) - 12343; return calculated});
const options =                                 
{
    address: getPair(tokenA, tokenB),
    fromBlock: calculated,
    toBlock: 'latest'

}
```